# Make Delphi IDE insert new code at the bottom of the editor

Tags: ide, delphi

I have moved from using Delphi7 to Delphi XE5 and I have noticed what I consider to be an annoying "feature" in the IDE that I would like to disable.

What I am talking about is when you place a control on your form and double click it, Delphi will automatically insert the default procedure code for the control into the editor window and this is nice and all, but in Delphi7 it used to insert this procedure code at the `bottom` of the code editor window and now in XE5 (probably other versions as well) it will insert the procedure code somewhere in the `middle` of my code and I always have to move it down to the bottom which is annoying to me and I would like to change this behavior so it works like it used to in Delphi 7. Any suggestions ?

To reproduce the behavior I am talking about, start a new project and place a button (button1) on your form and double click it so it's default procedure code is inserted into the editor window, next place a label (label1) on the form and double click it and again the default procedure code is inserted at the bottom of editor window after the button1 procedure code, so far so good. Finally, place a new button (button2) on the form and double click it and you will notice that the procedure code for button 2 is inserted above the label 1 code and not at the bottom of the editor which is not the behavior I want and wish to change.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you want, more of a tip. I also like the default behaviour in Delphi 7, but usually find I want to move the inserted code anyway. Try putting a numbered bookmark at the point you want to add code using CTRL+SHIFT+ (eg. CTRL+SHIFT+1) at the bottom of the file. You can then toggle to the bookmark with CTRL+1. Double-click the control, cut the code, press CTRL+1 and paste.

These numbered bookmarks are a *huge* productivity boost. Works for all numbers 0-9.